# Flexbox grid: How to display 3 items side-by-side but varying vertical positions

Tags: css, flexbox

The red boxes are the items, the grey background is the container:

[image]

I have 3 items that I want to display in a container. Please see the included image. 
What is the best way to go about this using flexbox? It should be the same on mobile view. 
Thanks

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox, with nth-child to change the specific heights of the flex objects.

EX:

```
//HTML
<div class="container">
    <div class="flex"></div>
    <div class="flex"></div>
    <div class="flex"></div>
</div>

//CSS
.container{
  background: #AAA;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  height: 15vw;
  width: 20vw;
  }
.flex{
  background: #F00;
  height: 7vw;
  margin-left: 1.25vw;
  width: 5vw;
  }
.flex:nth-child(1){
  margin-top: 6vw;
  }
.flex:nth-child(2){
  margin-top: 1vw;
  }
.flex:nth-child(3){
  margin-top: 5vw;
  }
```

See an example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mn8ukbae/7/

Comment: Glad I could help. If you genuinely found it helpful, would you mind clicking the checkmark next to my answer that marks the question as "answered"? It will help others on this site find this solution in the future should they need it.

Answer (score 0):

with flex you have the `align-self` property, which can be used to align an element on the cross-axis differently from the others, within the same flex parent.

```
.container { display: flex; }
.item--1 { align-self: flex-end; }
.item--2 { align-self: flex-start; }
.item--3 { align-self: center; }
```

I could almost bet my life that this is a 'homework' exercise, and you would do well to read up on `flex` and `align-self` to make the most of it.